# Remove span and the following text

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to remove the `span#visitor_count` plus the text that follows before `span#visitor_list`.

I have the below code to remove the `span` but how can I remove the text that follows? I need to remove `leaguemates on-line:` which gets populated with all the members names who are online.

```
$("#league_chat span#visitor_count").remove();
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<form action="" name="chat">
    <input type="text" name="chat" id="chat_text_field" size="30" maxlength="200"> 
    <input type="button" onclick="postChatMessage();" value="Post"> 
    <a href="javascript:toggle_chat_audio();"></a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:document.chat.chat.value=':clear:'; postChatMessage();"></a>&nbsp;
    <a href="http://football25.myfantasyleague.com/2016/options?L=59810&amp;O=222" target="_blank"></a><br> 
    <span id="visitor_count">0</span> leaguemates on-line: 
    <span id="visitor_list"></span><br> Send Message To: 
    <select size="1" name="TO_FID" pmbx_context="3372F894-FBD9-49AC-86EF-D9BED91B61D3">
        <option value="">Everyone</option>
        <option value="0000">Commissioner</option>
        <option value="0001">TEST FRANCHISE 1</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you would need to get the `textNode` following the `span` using the `nextSibling` property, something like this:

```
var $visitorCount = $("#league_chat span#visitor_count");
$($visitorCount[0].nextSibling).remove(); // remove 'leaguemates on-line: '
$visitorCount.remove(); // remove the original span
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/tod3c91y/)

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap the text you want to remove in a span, and give that span an ID, you can remove it with `remove()`

HTML like this:

```
 <span id="visitor_count">0</span> <span id="online-leaguemates">leaguemates on-line: </span>
```

jQuery like this

```
$("#online-leaguemates").remove();
```

If you want to remove both, you could write

```
$("#online-leaguemates, #visitor_count").remove();
```

Comment: Then Rory McCrossan's answere is indeed the way to go with. It is much cleaner as well.